# \H{u} and \H{o} do not appear in the lualatex output PDF

Tags: luatex, input-encodings, font-encodings

The following .tex source file has been working fine for me for decades using *pdflatex*:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\def\myhelvetica{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvízt\H{u}r\H{o}}
\hrule
{\myhelvetica\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

The good output of *pdflatex* looks like:

[image: good output of pdflatex]

The bad output of *lualatex* (the 1st line is shorter) looks like:

[image: bad output of lualatex]

How do I fix it for *lualatex* without using Unicode fonts, TrueType fonts, OpenType fonts or `\usepackage{fontspec}`?

I'm using these on Linux:

- pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)
- LuaTeX, Version 1.07.0 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian)

Comment: It is my understanding that the font handling from pdfLaTeX can't or shouldn't be used in LuaLaTeX. In particular `lmodern` (and probably `t1enc`) are out in LuaLaTeX. And if you want to change the font in LuaLaTeX Open Type and `fontspec` are what you would use. So if you exclude that, there is not a lot (nothing?) left for you to use.

Comment: @egreg: Which feature of which package breaks exactly in my example document?  How exactly is *lualatex* different from *pdflatex* in this situation? Can you cite some documents I can read about this specific difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `inputenc` into `luainputenc`. But, really, you should switch to OpenType fonts. Don't complain if hyphenation is weird.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\def\myhelvetica{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvízt\H{u}r\H{o}}
\hrule
{\myhelvetica\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

For completeness, the `fontspec` version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\myhelvetica{TeX Gyre Heros}

\begin{document}

\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule
{\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvízt\H{u}r\H{o}}
\hrule
{\myhelvetica\Huge Helló, Wörld, árvíztűrő}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! The source file with `luainputenc` works correctly with *xelatex*, *pdflatex* and *lualatex*. I haven't checked hyphenation though.

Comment: About hyphenation: With old-style (non-*fontspec*) fonts in *lualatex*, hyphenation of words containing Latin-1 letters is correct; hyphenation of words containing letters outside Latin-1 (e.g. \H{o}, or just ő) is incorrect. Hyphenation of everything is correct in *pdflatex*. Hyphenation of everything is correct with *lualatex* and *fontspec* fonts.

Comment: @pts That's what I said: you can get the right characters with `luainputenc`, but not hyphenation.

Comment: Any insights why hyphenation is broken (and how it can be fixed)? Is it because patterns are in Unicode (UTF-8), but characters are in T1 encoding? (This would explain the behavior I'm experiencing.) Is there hack which converts patterns back to T1 encoding?

Comment: @pts Hyphenation is not broken. It just happens that it is available only for T1 encoded fonts or for Unicode fonts. Mixtures are not supported, as each variation would need a specific set of hyphenation patterns.

Comment: Theoretically it can be fixed: *lualatex* knows that font is not Unicode, and that the hyphenation patterns for that language is in Unicode, and in this case *lualatex* could convert the hyphenation patterns to T1 encoding, to make them work with that the font. Since it can be fixed, but it isn't fixed, I came to the conclusion that *it's broken*'. (Probably it's worth asking in another question how it can be fixed.)